How to write a simple async test for fetch api call in React Testing Library
I have a React component as follows. The fetch api is called once the dom load is complete. I want to display the data as a list which is received from the api call.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const GetData= () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://openlibrary.org/people/george08/lists.json");         
        const data = await response.json();
        const { entries } = data;
        setLists(entries);
      } catch(error) {
         setError(error);
      }  
    }
    getData();
  }, [])

  let listContent = <h1>Loading....</h1>;

  if (lists.length) {
    listContent = (
      <ul role='booklist'>
        {
          lists.map(list => (
            <li key={list.url}>{list.name}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
    return <>{listContent}</>;
}

export default GetData;

I am very new with React Testing Library. All the example which I am finding are not helping me much in writing the test. Can someone please provide pointers.
Also, I have tried a below test but it did not work for me
it('api success call', async () => {
    const mockData = [
      {
        full_url: "/people/george08/lists/OL95357L/Museum_in_a_Box",
        name: "Museum in a Box",
        url: "/people/george08/lists/OL95357L"
      }
    ]

    const mockedResponse = {
      config: {},
      data: {
        entries: mockData
      },
      headers: {},
      status: 200,
      statusText: '200',
    }

    const mRes = { json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedResponse) };
    const mockedFetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mRes);
    global.fetch = mockedFetch;

    render(<GetData />);
    screen.debug();

    await act(async () => {
      await waitFor(() => expect(mockedFetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1));
    });
  })


What's the issue, is there any error?  Show it.
